# Support of corba in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, corba

I want to write a simple client-server application using corba and java. I'm using Netbeans 6.8 IDE, but I can't find any plugin for corba in my netbeans version. So, my question:
Is there any plugin or smth else to add support of corba to netbeans?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your usecase, but there is something else. Use Java RMI over IIOP. It is part of the Java SDK and has nothing to do with Netbeans or any other IDE you prefer to use.

You can find some general documentation at [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi-iiop/index.html).